# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while sending patch req in

Tags: node.js, express, http, fetch-api

When I send a patch request with the following code :

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/data', {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "formulaString": formula,
                    "index": props.id
                })
            })
```

I get an error on my console saying `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

But on the server side, it seems like I am getting the request.
the code on my server looks like :

```
app.patch('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    ....
})
```

Basically every time I initiate a request, I get an error on the client side but the server side works as intended(the `console.log(req.body)` works)

Why would this happen?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Which request is being refused, the `PATCH` or pre-flight `OPTIONS`? Some screenshots from your dev-tools _Network_ panel would help. Also, are you providing a response at all, ie `res.send(/* something */)`?

Comment: Are you sending something like `res.status(200)` or `res.send('something')`? Maybe it's possible that you are doing some operation after that console.log that hangs the nodejs thread forever. If you are doing a promise, try to handle errors with `catch`.